# Finding row based on the number of occurrence of the where clause

Tags: sql

I have a table defined as this:

```
CREATE TABLE A_TEST  (
    "ID"   NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "TYPE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
)
```

- ID is not a primary key.
- TYPE might be NULL
- An ID I can have 0, 1 or more TYPEs.

if I want to get IDs with differents types I will write this query:

```
SELECT distinct a1.ID FROM A_TEST a1
  JOIN A_TEST a2 on a2.ID = a1.ID and a2.type != a1.type
```

But how can I find Ids for which I have a single type defined?
(only one row for Id or many rows for id with only one having a type defined)

Comment: Can you have more than one rows with same ID and same Type?

Comment: no, that should not be possible

Comment: You should then add a `UNIQUE (ID, TYPE)` constarint. Otherwise, the database will allow it. Both answers seem correct with this clarification.

Comment: You should tell us what should be done if for an ID, there is a single row with NULL type and what if there are many rows, all with NULL types. Then we'll know which of the two answers fits your requirements exactly.

Comment: I was more interested on how to express such a request than to solve a precise use case. The example is a barebone extraction from a real table, but I was not able to express how to filter it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the clarifications, it seems that your requirements are:

```
SELECT ID
FROM A_TEST
GROUP BY ID    
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TYPE) = 1
    OR COUNT(*) = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 4):

The following query will return all IDs that have only one TYPE in the table.

```
SELECT ID FROM A_TEST
WHERE TYPE IS NOT NULL -- since TYPE column can be NULL for a given ID.
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE A_TEST ( ID INT, TYPE INT)
INSERT INTO A_TEST VALUES(1, NULL)
INSERT INTO A_TEST VALUES(2, 0)
INSERT INTO A_TEST VALUES(3, 0)
INSERT INTO A_TEST VALUES(3, 1)
INSERT INTO A_TEST VALUES(4, 1)
INSERT INTO A_TEST VALUES(4, 1)
INSERT INTO A_TEST VALUES(5, 0)
INSERT INTO A_TEST VALUES(5, NULL)

SELECT 
    ID 
FROM 
    A_TEST
WHERE 
    TYPE IS NOT NULL -- since TYPE column can be NULL for a given ID.
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1
```

Result

```
ID
-----------
2
4
(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I did not donwnvote but I can answer why. Probably because it's wrong. Your query will show IDs with one row in the table, not IDs with one type.

Comment: @ypercube, thanks for the response. The `GROUP BY` clause aggregates the rows by ID and since one type means one row, it will show those IDs with one record where the TYPE column is not null.

Comment: And if you have 2 rows, both with `(4,1)`? Will `4` be shown in the result?

Comment: @ypercube, yes it does, updated the response (done on SQL Express).

Comment: I see one row with `(4,1)`, not two.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't understand the WHERE TYPE IS NOT NULL clause. If I have (4, a) and (4, NULL) I would like to have 4 in my results. In your example I want to have 1, 2 and 4. If I insert (1,0), I still want to have ID 1 in the result.

Comment: Since you want to have 4 when your table has (4, a) and (4, NULL), the `WHERE TYPE IS NOT NULL` will eliminate the first row and so `4` will be part of the result.

Comment: @ypercube, sorry, I didn't see "2 rows" in your previous comment. I think this was not a case as per OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

This example takes into account NULL valued types:

```
SELECT ID
FROM A_TEST
WHERE TYPE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ID    
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TYPE)=1
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aee30/3) for example